# Drawing Rectangle inside TableLayout in Android app

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a TableLayout in my android application.

I want some Rectangles of dynamic size as the elements of the table. Using canvas I drew the rectangle, now how can I place those rectangles in my table's columns.

I'm new to android please help,
Thanks,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `canvas` in method `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` of class `View`.
Here is my example:
`CustomView` class extends TextView class:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint paint = new Paint();
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // draw rectangle and text
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-2, getHeight()-2, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(2, 2, getWidth()-4, getHeight()-4, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), 6, getHeight()-getPaddingBottom()-6, paint);
}
```

in Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    table.addView(tr);
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    tr.addView(new CustomView(this));
    table.addView(tr);
    setContentView(table);
}
```